# Get encoding bug in Jupyter when writing and reading binary file using Python

Tags: python, encoding, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I executed the following code in Jupyter, trying to deal with a binary file called **bfile**. However, when I opened the file in Jupyter, I got the error message as shown in the picture below. And when I opened the file using Notepad, I got a bunch of messy characters. Anyone call help (please be plain in language, I'm not familiarized with encoding issues like UTF, Unicode in my daily work)?

```
bdata = bytes(range(0, 256))
with open('bfile', 'wb') as fin:
    fin.write(bdata)
with open('bfile', 'rb') as fin:
    fin.seek(-1, 2)
    fin.tell()
```

[image]

**Error message**

Error! Y:\Desktop\bfile is not UTF-8 encoded

Saving disabled.

See Console for more details.

**The messy characters I got when I opened the file using Notepad are,**
[image]

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: Is it a Python 2 workspace or Python 3?

Comment: Python 3. And I use Anaconda.@erip

Comment: You say you're getting the exception when you "checked the file". What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Corrected@Blckknght

Comment: The error message is very uncear, and a-typical of a Python error message. At what point in the listed code do you get your error?

Comment: Binary data is binary data: it doesn't care about encodings. Your example code saves the data as a binary file, and reads it as binary as well. I don't see how you get a UTF-8 error.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem when trying to write a binary file to the file system.  Could it be a Jupyter bug ?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to try and open the binary file you just written (with just the binary values 0 to 255 inclusive) in Jupyter. That's not how Jupyter works: what is it supposed to do with that (random) binary file?

Jupyter can open e.g. notebook files. It will likely also open plain text files, or even image files, because it read them either as text, or pass the handling of the file (images) to the filebrowser.
Jupyter has no idea what to do with your binary file: it is not a known specification.

If, instead, you want to use the binary data *inside Python*, then read the file within Python. In fact, your code sample already shows that you're doing that, so I'm not sure why you're also trying to open your binary file inside Jupyter  (or Notepad. Note that Notepad tries the best it can with your binary file, and shows the ASCII values for 0 to 255 on your system, as far as it can. Hence you see ranges of known characters. It won't show you the integer values 0 to 255, but assumes some encoding and translates those values to characters, according to that encoding. Probably not ASCII, but some Windows ASCII-like encoding).

Comment: You're right, my code block doesn't throw an error when executed in the Jupyter console. So do you mean that a binary file is supposed to be read in Python (using .read(), for instance), but makes no sense to open it and see it directly? In Python, if I ran this `with open('bfile', 'rb') as fin:
    bdata = fin.read()
    print(bdata)`, I can see the result (bytes object), but why the result is not written in the text file (binary file)?

Comment: What do you expect Jupyter to do when it opens your binary file? Jupyter expects Python code (e.g., a notebook file).